# i try to upload file in my mocha nodejs test but i got [Object null prototype] { file: { ... }}

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, mocha.js

i find evrywhere solution white :

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

i can use

```
JSON.stringify(req.files)
```

but im sur having a way to fix my problem

my mocha test :

```
it('a file', async function () {
        const body = { pseudo: 'user', password: 'test@123', mail: 'supermail' };

        const response = await fetch(hostName + '/authentication/register', {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
        const usr = await response.json();
        request.post('/usrAction1/doc')
            .field('token', usr.token)
            .attach('file', 'test/test.pdf')
            .end(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
                console.log(res.status) // 'success' status
            });
    });
```

and my rout handler :

```
router.post('/doc', async (req, res) => {
        console.log('req.files');
        console.log(req.files)

 })
```

also my server.js:

```
import express from 'express'
import authentication from './src/login.js'
import './global/host.js'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cors from "cors"
import verifyToken from './middleware/auth.js'
import { userAction1, userAction2 } from './src/userAction.js'
import verifyLevel from './middleware/level.js'
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';

export default function myApp() {
    const whitelist = [/http:\/\/localhost:*/, /http:\/\/127.0.0.1:*/]

    const corsConfig = { origin: whitelist }

    const app = express();
    const port = hostPort;

    //json encoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(cors(corsConfig))

    // enable files upload
    app.use(fileUpload({
        createParentPath: true
    }));

    app.use('/usrAction1', userAction1())

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
    return app;
}
myApp();
```

but don't to work for me .
i also test white external client server who juste runing a form and send it to my tested adress and
do the same [Object null prototype]

thank u for evry litel help

Answer (score 0):

i waiting of some help i using this magique code i found somwhere on stackoverflow:

`req.files && Object.keys(req.files)?.map((obj, idx) => { console.log(req.files['file'].data) })`

if somone have a better idea i waiting .

thank to all

Comment: i juste mistake i calling my path whitout sending  file in one of my test so that make sens now